# Bind the request data to a model manually instead of it being in the action's parameters list

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I have an action that handles different kinds (but similar) requests. So I need the request data to bind to different models depending on several external inputs.

Is there a way to do that (so that the model isn't in the action's parameters list but bound manually)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing your own `IActionModelConvention` realisation, you can change the parameter binding rules.

Article, that may help: [Customising model-binding conventions in ASP.NET Core](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-core-customising-model-binding-conventions)

[Here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/a78f77afde003c4a3fcf5dd7b6dc13dd9c85f825/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim/Conventions/WebApiParameterConventionsApplicationModelConvention.cs) and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/a78f77afde003c4a3fcf5dd7b6dc13dd9c85f825/test/WebSites/ApplicationModelWebSite/readme.md) are examples in MVC github repo.

Comment: Nice. I had hoped it would be as easy as calling a method to do manual binding but this is good enough.